# Derivative, Velcity, Acceleration and MIT Pumpkin

Tags: derivatives

[image]

A pumpkin is thrown-up from a MIT building as shown in 1st graph. 2nd graph is of its velocity (first derivative) and 3rd one is of acceleration (2nd derivative).

PROBLEM: I can't relate the reality of the motion of the pumpkin with the graphs.

**Reality of Velocity:** When we throw the pumpkin, its speed (velocity) starts to decrease and become zero at top and then speed starts to increase but since velocity is *speed with direction* and direction is downwards, hence velocity graph is going down. This means  increase in velocity is being represented as negative number and a downward graph, I wonder how will one represent decreasing velocity, with a positive number and upward direction ?)

**Reality of Acceleration:** Going up pumpkin is de-accelerating (decreasing) and going down it is accelerating (increasing) but graph is constant, just straight line. By looking only at the graph of acceleration and without looking at velocity and the first graph, one can conclude acceleration was constant negative number. Hence when we throw anything up, it just continues to de-accelerate even when it falls down. Logic is wrong but that is what the graph says.

Comment: They are vectors and we usually  choose the up direction to be the positive one. That's all.

Comment: Notice that if the number -2 decreases, its absolute value increases.

Comment: @tst Oh.. I need to learn Vectors then. 2nd,  how |-2| is related here ?

Comment: De-acceleration is an opinion and it is mostly used when the absolute value of the velocity decreases. You shouldn't think in this terms, there is only acceleration that measures the rate of change of the velocity.

Comment: You mean, while doing Math, I should not think  of real-life experience of (de-)acceleration but more of as just a 2nd derivative like any other equation ?

Comment: No, I mean that when you write down equations you should know what the symbols represent.

Comment: Tell me if I got it. I should think of acceleration in terms of rate of change of velocity and that's it, never in terms of de-acceleration or acceleration in real life.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "real life". You choose a direction that is positive. The other direction is negative. If the acceleration is positive, the velocity increases. If it is negative, it decreases. Just notice that $-2>-3$. So if the velocity changes from $-2$ to $-3$ it decreases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re using the word *acceleration* to mean two different, though related, things.

In colloquial usage (what you all “real life”), to accelerate means to increase *speed*, and to decelerate means to decrease *speed*. However, you’re working with velocities, which are directed—here signed—quantities. In this context, the word “acceleration” refers to *any* change in velocity, regardless of whether it increases or decreases the object’s *speed*, which is the velocity’s absolute value. This acceleration is also a signed quantity, but to determine whether it corresponds to an increase or decrease in speed, you also have to consider the sign of the velocity: when the signs are the same, the *speed* increases—an “acceleration” in the first sense above; when the signs differ, the *speed* decreases—a “deceleration.”

Comment: I think I I understoond most of it.  One last thing, in our pumpkin example., acceleration and velocity are both increasing and both  have same sign (negative), then why is that only velocity graph is showing increase in velocity while acceleration graph shows  constant ?

Comment: Not at all. Until the pumpkin reaches its maximum height, the velocity and acceleration have different signs—the pumpkin slows down. Once the pumpkin starts dropping, they have the same sign—the pumpkin speeds up. The acceleration (due to gravity) is constant throughout.

Comment: Oh no, they are talking about acceleration due to gravity and I was confusing it with acceleration of the "throw". I was thinking this way: the force with which pumpkin is thrown up makes velocity up and acceleration up.  That acceleration is not taken into account I see.

Comment: @Arnuld The initial impetus is instantaneous in this simplified model. If you like, assume that the pumpkin had already been set in motion before you started tracking it. Either way, there is no upward component of acceleration during the time that is being shown.

Comment: understood. Thanks

Comment: I’ll just add here that when you look at motion in two or more dimensions, you can have an acceleration that doesn’t change the object’s speed at all, e.g., uniform circular motion.